# How to prevent so many instances of apt-check running?

Tags: apt, memory-usage

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server that just crashed because of a very obvious cause: 30+ of `apt-check` processes consuming all memory, the OOM killer kicking in, killing vital services. I'm not sure where the `apt-check` processes come from, but I guess my Nagios/Icinga plugins `check_apt` might use it, as well as the `byobu` status line may want to display its output. I guess something locked up and all of the processes were just waiting, yet holding memory.

How can I prevent to have so many instances of `apt-check` on the system? It doesn't make sense to me and it should just quit as soon as it can't get a read lock on the dpkg database.

It seems that I'm not the only one running into trouble here. All suggestions for `apt-check` are pretty negative:

[image]

<sup>(clean browser, not logged in, no personalised search)</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some dive into `apt-check` gave me these clues for being it a very blunt script that needs fixing. With all due respect to the authors of it, it is failing on my servers. Here are my thoughts:

- `apt-check` == `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py`
- forces nicelevel 19 for itself
- no timeouts set on actions

The combination of the last two allows it to pile up endlessly in a spiral downwards. If the system is used for some other purposes with higher priority, the amount of processes will just increase and there's no end to it, as `apt-check` will never get any priority over it. Trouble will only get worse once the OOM killer decides to kill your vital system processes.

If either of these two aspects in behaviour was different, it would not allow the system to end up in such a broken state is my assumption.

While [strings is right](https://askubuntu.com/a/239402/88802) about the parent processes being responsible in this too, I believe below points are flaws in `apt-check` and has to be reported as a bug to get addressed properly:

- it should [hint the OOM killer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58872/how-to-set-oom-killer-adjustments-for-daemons-permanently) to have itself killed first
- it should not set the nicelevel hardcoded
- it should exit if it takes an unreasonable amount of time to get pieces of information

Actually, it seems that the Linux OOM killer is doing some heuristic on this. Niced processes will get an increased score, and long-running processes are decreased. ([source](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) - thanks to [Ulrich Dangel](https://askubuntu.com/users/82848/ulrich-dangel) for [pointing it out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7616115#7616115))

Possible solution I may propose:

- cache results after processing
- output cache if less than N amount of seconds *without loading all Python-APT libraries for every simple (even `--help`) invocation.*
- make the nicelevel configurable - *Allow me to change/disable this, please! I believe that setting it to 0 will actually help*
- have it increase the OOM killer score

Comment: I think you've missed the biggest thing it should do: use a lockfile and not allow more than one instance to run at once.

Comment: @derobert It's a script that any user can run, without specific privileges on Ubuntu, not a daemon. Or can I use `/var/run` / `/tmp` for this world-readable/writable lock file safely? Big hole there: add lock file and admin won't be notified of system updates!

Comment: Whatever is launching it automatically (leading to 30+ copies running) needs to do the locking. Or it could do it itself, per-user. Either way, that's a bug that needs to be solved.

Comment: Nagios/Icinga seems to avoid the pitfall.  At least, it had some 10s timeout and warned if it was exceeded.  (Though I can't find how to configure the timeout - I'd prefer longer).  Byobu on Debian is what caused the problem for me; on Ubuntu it's [supposed to be fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/byobu/+bug/1010505).

Answer (score 4):

You need to find out what process is spawning apt-check. you can use something like ps to get the process tree.

```
ps -A --forest
```

If apt-check has no parents, then it might be a issue with apt-check its self and not one particular program. if that is the case I would try to debug apt-check.

Comment: Thanks. Gave me some ideas to look further into. However, this lead me to believe it's a problem of `apt-check` really - see [my own answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/239530/88802).

Comment: If it's consuming memory and CPU time, it's not a zombie.

Comment: @Gilles good point.

Answer (score 0):

Written base on Ubuntu 12.04

I have the same problem and found out that's because of `byobu`, if I just run `apt-get update` not using `byobu`, there will be no `check-apt` process. Also, it relates to `update-notifier` package, when I removed those packages (update-notifer-common, update-notifier), using `byobu` and run `apt-get update`, it ran another command but quite the same memory using: `apt-get -s -o Debug::NoLocking=true upgrade`.

Some other things may run `apt-get update` (but probably do not run `check-apt`)

- passing argument to  `check_apt` to update/upgrade pkg.
- if configured, `/etc/cron.daily/apt` may update the package list, too
  (see https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html),
  but it just run once a day, and should not be problem.

On a desktop, there are more things may involved.

Conclude:
`byobu` catches the event when you run `apt-get update` and trigger these `check-apt` processes, re-config the status bar of `byobu` to fix this.